# Schedule Azure Server Reboot

Tags: azure, umbraco, schedule, reboot

We have a two server Azure configuration, running websites powered by Umbraco. When we need to add a new domain to the Azure servers, we amend a config file, and reboot each server in turn.

In theory, because we never reboot both servers at the same time, this shouldn't affect uptime. In practice, however, the load balancer doesn't respond quickly enough, and therefore we get approximately 20 minutes of downtime.

It would be much better if we could schedule a reboot at around 3 in the morning. Is there a feature within Azure that would allow us to schedule a reboot of both servers?

I've done some research on this topic, but as of yet I can't find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to schedule reboots. It's up to you to manage this.

You could for example create a Scheduled Task in Windows (on one of your servers) and call a [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841.aspx) script to reboot the servers.